# Scroll issue on display grid in flex container

Tags: scroll, flexbox, css-grid

I noticed a scroll issue when a display grid element is child of a flex one.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-on-scroll-flex-div-containing-grid-il0rh7)  an example to explain the problem

[image: scroll top issue]
As you can see in this screenshot, the scroll bar is at its maximum top position but the some of the grid content are hidden and there's no way to scroll them into view.

I have to use a flex box because my goal is to keep the grid centered horizontally and vertically
[image]

Any idea to solve?